# URL/Subdomain rewrite (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

My application dynamically creates sub domains.

If just the subdomain is used (no other path): `mydomain.mysite.com`

I need the subdomain to remap/rewrite (keep the same URL so its hidden from the user) to the following url `mydomain.mysite.com/event/mydomain`

In the instance where there are other parameters passed then I want to ignore the rewrite rule. (`mydomain.mysite.com/something/else`)

I'm having trouble with the following endind up in a redirect loop

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// %1.mysite.com/events/%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Its also rewriting when I pass other params!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `http://` as part of your rule's target, then it will automatically redirect. You want it to internally rewrite so remove the `http://` and hostname. You also want to match against the URI `/` because anything rlese you want to ignore the rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
# you may want this condition, to ignore "www"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ /events/%1 [L]
```

The first condition was added to ignore hosts that start with `www`, so that `http://www.mysite.com/` won't get rewritten. If you don't care about that then just remove the condition. You also don't need the `QSA` flag because that's implicit when you don't have a `?` in your target.

Comment: THanks for the reply.

I tried using those rules but when i ran subdomain.mysite.com it gives a 404 however subdomain.mysite.com/events/subdomain seems to run ok ? any ideas ?

Cheers