# Dynamic directory alias with Apach 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4, mod-alias

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a dynamic directory alias based on the requested subdomain.

If a user requests the URL **https://{subdomain}.site.com/images/** I would like the file system folder **/full/linux/path/to/{subdomain}/images/** to be served (not necessarily under the document root).

Tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
  Alias /images/ /path/to/%1/images/
</VirtualHost>
```

And

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
  SetEnvIf Host "^([^.]*)\." SUBDOMAIN=$1
  Alias /storage/ /path/to/%{ENV:SUBDOMAIN}/images/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Certainly that is possible. And you will find lots of already existing answers here on SO for that question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you consider my comment to the question "pointless" I will help you out...

Apache's `Alias` directive operates on paths, but rewriting easily allows what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?images/(.*)$ /path/to/%1/images/$1 [QSA,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

And to come back to my initial comment to your question here is a spontaneous collection of existing answers here on SO demonstrating the same thing:

- [Apache Rewrite: image directory based on HTTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151876/apache-rewrite-image-directory-based-on-http-host)
- [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)
- [htaccess subdomain rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407029/htaccess-subdomain-rewrite)
- [Apache rewrite based on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500/apache-rewrite-based-on-subdomain)
- [URL/Subdomain rewrite (htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616669/url-subdomain-rewrite-htaccess)
- ...

Comment: Now that's something that deserves appreciation! I wanted to escape from the fact that all files needed to be under the document root. I had attempted AliasMatch VirtualAlias etc. If this is the only option, then mod_rewrite it is.